# Converting to an Ascii Character Set in Informix database

Tags: database, database-design, character-encoding, ascii, informix

Overview: In Informix is it possible to enforce ASCII for a database or instance.

Details: I am trying to enforce `ASCII` in an instance of informix for a while. This is to help have a smooth transition between char sets: `ISO Latin-1 (819)` and `UTF8`. I would like this to be done by cleansing my current data of non `ASCII` characters and then exporting the data from the databases. These steps have already been done.

Then setting the character set to enforce `ASCII`. However I cannot find a character set that I can use that my instance allows me to change the `db_locale` too. My current `db_locale` is default aka `ISO Latin 1` or `819`. After I figure out the character set. I believe that I can figure out the rest. It should be just importing the data to a new database with the `db_locale` set to an `ASCII` char set.

Is this possible? I am also open to other ways of setting or enforcing `ASCII` at the database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the same question I posted on Database Administrators:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/199275/converting-and-or-enforcing-an-ascii-character-set-in-informix-database-from-819

If you do not want to go and read the answer there I will summarize what was said. It is not very easily possible to enforce `ASCII` at a database level since Informix does not have a character set they support that is only `ASCII`. It could be possible with a GLS character set. However that is not trivial but at the same time not hard. --This answer came from Jonathan Leffler.